# Property in interface cannot have a backing field

Tags: android, properties, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am learning [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org). My code is as follows:

```
   interface BaseLogicDecoupler<A : BaseViewNotifier, B : BaseScreenRouter> {

        var notifier: A?
        var router: B?

        fun attachNotifier(notifier: A?) {
            this.notifier = notifier
        }

        fun detachNotifier() {
            notifier = null;
        }

        fun attachRouter(router: B?) {
            this.router = router
        }

        fun detachRouter() {
            router = null;
        }
    }
```

But when I change it and try to provide an accessor for property like following :

```
var notifier: A?
    get() = notifier
```

It doesn't compile with error saying : **Property in interface cannot have a backing field**.

From the doc [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html), kotlin interfaces can provide implementation and can have properties with accessors. Why does the compilation fail?

I am unable to understand the error. What does it say? Can anyone explain in simple terms?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is an unexpected corner case, kudos to you for finding it.

Let me briefly explain it what goes on. I will use a stripped interface `A` and class `B` for the sake of simplicity:

```
interface A {
    var notifier: Int
}
```

Normally a `var` property in a class includes 3 components: a private `backing field` to store its value, a `setter` method to write to it and a `getter` method to read it. But an interface cannot have a field (because live is pain and some math does not add up if it does), so a `var` property in an interface includes only 2 components: a `setter` and a `getter`.

As I outlined above, our interface `A` has declared 2 methods: a `setter` and a `getter`, both without implementations. Let's add some implementations to it:

```
interface A2 {
    var notifier: Int
        get() {return 1}
        set(v) {}
}
```

So far, so good. Two `open` methods with implementations, non of them uses any fields. But what if only one of the implementations is declared?

```
interface A3 {
    var notifier: Int    //ERROR: Property in an interface cannot have a backing field
        get() {return 1}
        //set(v) {}
}
```

It turns out that if you specify only a `getter`, Kotlin also generates a (default) `setter` for the property. In other words, `A3` is similar to `A4` here:

```
interface A4 {
    var notifier: Int
        get() {return 1}
        set(v) {field = v}  //Obviously an error
}
```

This may be a bug or an intended behaviour. Here is the issue ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15193

**Possible workarounds:**

- declare an adequate setter as in `A2`
- use an `abstract class` instead of an interface

Comment: I ended up using abstract class. But frustrating thing is that I found no documentation anywhere. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you report it on JetBrains issue tracker, please do not forget to send me link here. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.

Comment: You could use val instead of var (if it suits for your purpose) and just define get() without a set() (Case A3)

Comment: Voted the issue. More than two years later, it still haunts Kotlin.

Comment: One question, if there is no backing field behind a var in interface, then where the value will be stored?